# All Demonym's in their native language

Tags: data-request, language, global

```
COUNTRY - ? / ?
US - American / Americans
UK - English / English
DE - Deutscher / Deutsche
```

Anyone an idea where to find this? We're trying to find any sort of source for this for weeks now.

Comment: By the way, this info isn't always objective. For example, the formal (and perhaps proper) demonynm in English is [US American](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/US_American)

Comment: obviously we want the natives way of saying it in their language - the super official document paper US American might be not the "common" use case at all. but here is the thing: it seems there isn't any database for this anyway, so whatever form it is is okay... ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a great internationalization project at

```
https://github.com/mledoze/countries
```

But unfortunately it only includes English demonyms. You might consider expanding the repo if you find a good data source.

```
{  
   "name":{  
      "common":"Germany",
      "official":"Federal Republic of Germany",
      "native":{  
         "deu":{  
            "official":"Bundesrepublik Deutschland",
            "common":"Deutschland"
         }
      }
   },
   "tld":[  
      ".de"
   ],
   "cca2":"DE",
   "ccn3":"276",
   "cca3":"DEU",
   "cioc":"GER",
   "currency":[  
      "EUR"
   ],
   "callingCode":[  
      "49"
   ],
   "capital":"Berlin",
   "altSpellings":[  
      "DE",
      "Federal Republic of Germany",
      "Bundesrepublik Deutschland"
   ],
   "region":"Europe",
   "subregion":"Western Europe",
   "languages":{  
      "deu":"German"
   },
   "translations":{  
      "deu":{  
         "official":"Bundesrepublik Deutschland",
         "common":"Deutschland"
      },
      "fra":{  
         "official":"R\u00e9publique f\u00e9d\u00e9rale d'Allemagne",
         "common":"Allemagne"
      },
      "hrv":{  
         "official":"Njema\u010dka Federativna Republika",
         "common":"Njema\u010dka"
      },
      "ita":{  
         "official":"Repubblica federale di Germania",
         "common":"Germania"
      },
      "jpn":{  
         "official":"\u30c9\u30a4\u30c4\u9023\u90a6\u5171\u548c\u56fd",
         "common":"\u30c9\u30a4\u30c4"
      },
      "nld":{  
         "official":"Bondsrepubliek Duitsland",
         "common":"Duitsland"
      },
      "por":{  
         "official":"Rep\u00fablica Federal da Alemanha",
         "common":"Alemanha"
      },
      "rus":{  
         "official":"\u0424\u0435\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0420\u0435\u0441\u043f\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u0413\u0435\u0440\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f",
         "common":"\u0413\u0435\u0440\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f"
      },
      "spa":{  
         "official":"Rep\u00fablica Federal de Alemania",
         "common":"Alemania"
      },
      "fin":{  
         "official":"Saksan liittotasavalta",
         "common":"Saksa"
      }
   },
   "latlng":[  
      51,
      9
   ],
   "demonym":"German",
   "landlocked":false,
   "borders":[  
      "AUT",
      "BEL",
      "CZE",
      "DNK",
      "FRA",
      "LUX",
      "NLD",
      "POL",
      "CHE"
   ],
   "area":357114
}
```

Comment: see that's the problem - after looking for 2 weeks, there seems to be no single source that lists demonyms and noun and adjective in the countries native language. it's crazy... the data above is still very helpful but still. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry or this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag?
They called locale codes BTW.

Comment: not the language tags etc. the name of the nationality. example would be US country citizen would be a "American" or "Americans", that's what I want. the nationalities/population/citizen name in their own language.
a german citizen is called a Deutscher many are called Deutsche, etc. that for every country and in it's own language.

"identifying terms for citizens - noun and adjective"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these wikidata entries for nationalities? https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Q231002